# Using multiple chats on one page with socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Ok so im trying to build a social messaging page on a project that i'm working on. This page has a chat for each user and their corresponding recipient.

All of these chats are on the same page and load/disappear on click events happening within a menu that contains all of the users that the currently logged in user has created a chat with.

I currently have the app set up so that the user can send a message to another user, the message gets entered into a database, and displayed on the screen.

I also have it so that when a user connects to the page, the server console displays 'Users connected: x' with x being the number of users connected.

What i need is that when a user clicks a button in the menu, it makes the user join a socket.io room for that user that they clicked on, then if they click on another chat it removes the user from their current chat and joins the next chat.

I know the syntax for most of how to do this but i can't work out where to put stuff. It seems from docs that you write the socket.join('room name') code on the server end when the user first connects to the socket, which is confusing me since i need the user to join and leave dynamically on the same page.

Comment: When the user is supposed to join a room, on the client you do `io.send("join", { room: "room123" })`. On the server, you have `socket.on("join", data => { socket.join(data.room); })` (you're essentially forwarding the intention to join from the client to the server)

Comment: This is the kind of question that is clarified by finding a good tutorial on socket.io, and reading through it (probably while coding along). As a "how do I X?" question, about code, without code, this is [not a good question](/help/how-to-ask) yet, and even quite likely an [off-topic](/help/on-topic) question until you start writing the actual code after finding a tutorial yourself, and learning more about how to implement socket.io-based code.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks chris, this really helped. Would the server side code go in the `io.on('connection, function(socket){})` block?

Comment: Exactly, that's where you set up how the server reacts to client messages.